# problems with a random number/letter generating script using the python random module

Tags: python-3.x, random

So I'm a bit of a Python beginner and I am wondering if there is a way to modify or fix this script so that it generates random number/letter sequences. I think I've got the actual *generation* solved, but I need some help on how to print the result to the console. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    import random
    random.random() * 10
    myList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    random.choice(myList)
    print(random.random() * 10 + random.choice(myList))
main()
```

Can any of you guys help me out? as I said before, I am a beginner, so it might be a basic mistake and examples in answers would be great.

Error edited in:

> ```
> line 9, in main
>     print(random.random() * 10 + random.choice(myList))
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
> ```

Comment: 2/5 of your code does nothing: `random.random()*10` and `random.choice(mylist)` - you are calling methods and do not use the `returns`. What do you want to achieve with those calls? The last `print` statement will not work, you have to make a string `str(93.2923)` from your random float first - before you concattenate it with a string by using `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print a float, make a string from it:

```
def main():
    import random
    # random.random() * 10     # does nothing, you do not use the return
    myList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o",
              "p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    # random.choice(myList)    # does nothing, you do not use the return
    print(str(random.random() * 10) + random.choice(myList)) 
    # prints a [0.0-1.0[ * 10 + one character

main()
```

You can benefit from using a constant from string instead of your list - and probably want to use some other functions to draw from the list:

```
import string
import random

# prints random 20 lowercase chars w/o repeat
print(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,20))    # see doku for sample()

# print random 20 lowercase chars with repeat
print(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase,k=20)) # see doku for choices()

# prints the same char multiple times
print(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) * random.randint(5,20))
```

Output:

```
['i', 'q', 's', 'z', 'g', 'v', 'r', 'j', 'h', 'u', 'y', 'p'
 , 'n', 't', 'k', 'c', 'm', 'a', 'x', 'd']

['f', 'x', 'u', 'x', 'a', 'l', 'f', 'u', 'l', 'x', 'j', 'i'
 , 'v', 'f', 'd', 'u', 'l', 'x', 'j', 'w']

rrrrrrrr  # this one varies in char and amounts...
```

[Doku of random - functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html) read up about `sample`, `choices` and `random`

[Doku of string - constants](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)
your lower case list is already a constant there.